# Is it possible to dump the successful login cookie to the site and bypass the session?

Tags: php, captcha, php-curl, forms, http-post

Here is the question :

Two case :

1:If there is Captcha existed ,may I use php-cURL to post the ID ,PW  & Captcha successful cookiefile to my site ?

2.If there is no Captcha existed ,may I just dump the successful login cookie to my site ? (someway of cookie injection  )

Can I use these two methods to get into the next direct pages (successful login page ,with PHP session )

Answer (score 0):

As I answered to a previous question of yours (which you deleted), setting Cookies in PHP cURL then going to pages only accesible if you are logged in will show their content instead of asking you to log in.

This practice is against those websites terms for sure, so I encourage you to not use it if you do not have explicit permission.

Comment: what if I just dump the successful login cookie ? (sth like cookie injection )

Comment: More details are needed though... If you have some cookies like `"loginKey"`, `"name"` etc. they may have a verification system and you should paste all of them.

Comment: watch?v=KTRfotUR3Is  This is what I tried to do .But it is not successful though . There is no  successful login cookie .

Comment: Users here (usually) will not give you the full answer. If you want to achieve something, you have to do it by your work. Read both my answers and you will succeed in your task.

Answer (score 0):

`may I use php-cURL to post the ID ,PW & Captcha successful cookiefile to my site ?` yes.

`may I just dump the successful login cookie to my site ?` yes.

`(someway of cookie injection )` - uhh, no, not directly, you can't inject cookies for other domains through your own website. but if you can write code on the target website, you can make a page that will inject cookies from a post parameter, but be careful to have such post data encrypted & authenticated before injection, an improper implementation of such a scheme could easily be a security issue.

`Can I use these two methods to get into the next direct pages` - you can just fetch it with curl..?

Comment: For your both "yes", my meaning is that I want to redirect to the targeted website next-page with that user authentication .Are the answers still yes ?

Comment: `you can just fetch it with curl..?` -yes , I wonder it won't .As I ve known that , the curl cannot do the page redirect .